# Remove entries from a List of objects by comparing it with another List

Tags: c#, .net, list, algorithm, logic

I need to remove all entries from a `List<Dto>`, say `master[]`, in which  another list in present , ie `Dto.ListOfIds`, say `a[]` which is a `List<int>`. I have another List , `List<int>` ,say `b[]`, which I need to compare with `a[]` and remove all entries from `master[]` where `a[]` and `b[]` have ***no common elements***.

Adding some code snippets ..hope this helps

```
var projectIds = invoiceListRequestDto.ProjectIds.Split(",").Select(int.Parse).Distinct().ToList();
invoiceList.ForEach(invoice=>
      {
      var invoiceProjectIds = invoice.ProjectReferenceNo.Split(",").Select(int.Parse).Distinct().ToList();
      if(invoiceProjectIds.Any(x=> projectIds.Any(t=> x==t)))
       {
         //logic here               
       }
      });
```

invoiceList is `master[]` , projectIds is `a[]` and invoiceProjectIds is `[b]`.
Actually , `a[]` and `b[]` are made from coma seperated strings[FYI]

Adding some sample data..

let `master[]=[{other stuff , b="3,4,5,6" } ,a[]=[1,2]` and `b[]=[3,4,5,6]`.

Here , as `a[]` and `b[]` have no common elements , `master[]` should be null after operations.

Could anyone help me with this logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of explaining with langue please post some code with prepared lists and array that we can copy paste. And you will get an answer within minutes. Up to now it takes really effort and time to understand your question/scenario

Comment: Agree with Mong's comment.. At first I was thinking LINQ Except, but then that last sentence, i've no idea what means "remove all entries from master[] where a[] and b[] have no common elements` - so "if a intersect b is empty, clear master" ? Maybe don't "say" anything.. Give real world examples like "if no employees that took sick time also took a holiday then clear the bonuses list for the year"

Comment: Updated with a code snippet..hope that helps

Comment: Please put some example with data, what is input and what is expected output, it would be easier to understand what you want.

Comment: @Anve added a sample data.. hope that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things, you could add a helper method to parse the Ids:

```
IEnumerable<int> ParseInts(string csv)
{
    return csv.Split(",").Select(int.Parse).Distinct();
}
```

You shouldn't modify a list whilst iterating.

One approach would be to create a new list:

```
var projectIds = ParseInts(invoiceListRequestDto.ProjectIds).ToArray();
invoiceList = invoiceList
    .Where(x => ParseInts(x.ProjectReferenceNo).Intersect(projectIds).Any())
    .ToList();
```

Or you could use `List<T>.RemoveAll` to modify the list in place:

```
invoiceList.RemoveAll(x => !ParseInts(x.ProjectReferenceNo).Intersect(projectIds).Any());
```

Comment: Hey .. Is there anyway that this could work in an IQeryable filter method?